# Big Data Processing At the Click of a Button

Tags: web-applications, architecture, statistics, data-mining

If you have an application that performs some heavy calculation on a large data set, and the results must be returned as quickly as possible at the click of a button, what are some architectural designs that are used to make this work large scale?

For example, an application runs a simulation to predict future results, and then does some statistical analysis on that data along with historical data. There is a good amount of CPU to run the simulation and DB heavy with inserting, then lots of big DB reads to collect historical data, and more CPU to do statistical analyses.

In essence, there is lots of data to process (both CPU and IO intensive), and the results should theoretically be shown at the click of a button.

I understand that this is not always a realistic goal depending on the intensity, but what are some typical architectures to accomplish such a task?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics, I'd say preprocess/precalculate everything you can anticipate to speed up user queries.

Answer (score 3):

Google does this to return search results.

Check out Hadoop - http://hadoop.apache.org/ - and specifically, MapReduce.

"Hadoop MapReduce is a programming model and software framework for writing applications that rapidly process vast amounts of data in parallel on large clusters of compute nodes."

Answer (score 1):

Rob has suggested a nice approach using MapReduce.

I believe  this sort of processing is part of Data Mining process  and data mining process has different approach than traditional request response model.

As a bare minimum

create a single table (denormalized) and store all the necessary information in the this table and then when users needs the information in real time , just do a table lookup and get the information as quickly as possible.

but there are challenges to this approach and one of the major challenge is to populate the data in this de-normalized table.

most of the time , it can be done offline may be by a night job or something which populates this table when the load is minimum !

This approach is one of the approach used in when you see **"Customer who bought this item also bought”** in a typical e-commerce application.

for more information and reference , please see

1- Sql Server Analysis Services

2- Item to Item Collaborative Filtering ( esp. **refer Amazon implementation**)